# Installing unsigned drivers in Windows Vista automatically

Tags: windows-vista, drivers

I'm trying to install some unsigned drivers to a lot of computers while deploying them with Windows Vista Home Premium. I use devcon.exe to force Vista to use the correct drivers and that works, the problem is that I get a dialog about this drivers being unsigned. I solved this with an AutoIt script that pressed the correct button.

But now I got problems, I'm supposed to install this machines on multiple languages, my old AutoIt script looked for a button with the text "Install anyway" and pressed the button. Now the text varies depending on language and I have to many languages to keep track of.

Is there any good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for (as it may require some reboots), but you might be able to use the [Driver Signature Enforcement Overrider](http://www.ngohq.com/home.php?page=dseo) to waive the pop-up boxes.

Comment: Do you know if their test signing works on other machines than the one used when test signing the driver?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a case for pre-loading the drivers in the local driverstore? I thought that would allow you to include unsigned drivers, no questions asked?
You might need to use package manager for this, or the command line pnputil.

Comment: pnputil doesn't seem to do the work, I checked microsofts technet and found the following condition for this to work "The driver package is signed with a valid digital certificate, and that certificate is in the Trusted Publishers store." Do you know of any package manager I could use that could solve this?